# Can you use a motion sensor switch to control an outlet

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I am planning on installing some LED light strips in a closet full of shelves. I am using an A/C adapter (wall wart, brick, what have you) connected to the strip, which plugs into an outlet. I plan to have the outlet controlled by a light switch to provide on/off to the light strip.

Is it possible to use a motion sensor as the light switch?

Or, is there an easier way to get the LED lights to turn on automatically?

Answer (score 2):

> **Is it possible to use a motion sensor as the light switch?**

Yes. You can buy standalone sensors designed to switch lights on and off. There are both plug-in switches and ones that you hard-wire to your light fitting.

> **is there an easier way to get the LED lights to turn on automatically?**

It depends. You could use a microswitch on the closet door.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  They make 12V motion sensors.  They are actually cheaper than 120V sensors because the sensors proper run on low voltage DC, and thus do not need a mains power supply within the sensor.  That is the way to do it, if you don't mind the vampire load of the 12V power supply being on all the time.